# Does redirecting Tor traffic through a transparent squid3 caching proxy instance keep up the level of privacy granted by Tor?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

I'm using

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -s $TOR_INSTANCE_IP -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3128
sudo iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 3128 -j DROP
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
# <ref>http://wiki.squid-cache.org/ConfigExamples/Intercept/LinuxRedirect</ref>
```

in `/etc/rc.local` to cache my HTTP traffic with a transparent `squid3` instance (and it's working AFAIK). Would adding

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -s $TOR_INSTANCE_IP -p tcp --dport 9150 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 9150 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3128
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -s $TOR_INSTANCE_IP -p tcp --dport 9151 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 9151 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3128
```

before `sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE` (it's working as well AFAIK and https://check.torproject.org passes) have the same effect (caching of HTTP request in `tor-browser` 4.0.2) without decreasing the level of privacy provided by an instance of `tor-browser` with default settings?